# Como envió un mail con cita o reunión con VB.net

Tags: vb.net, email, visual, studio

Buen día, quisiera saber como puedo mandar un correo electrónico con una cita para que se pueda agregar ya sea a los dispositivos móviles o a Outlook usando vb.net

Actualmente mi código es el siguiente

```
Sub EnvioEmail_Cotizacion(ByVal Correo As String, ByVal Mesaje As String, Asunto As String, ByRef Send As Boolean, Adjunto As String, CorreoAgente As String, N_Pedido As String)
        Dim _Message As New System.Net.Mail.MailMessage()
        Dim _SMTP As New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient
        Try
            'CONFIGURACIÓN DEL STMP
            _SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("cotizaciones@miempresa.com.mx", "Contraseña")
            _SMTP.Host = Host
            _SMTP.Port = Puerto
            _SMTP.EnableSsl = False

            ' CONFIGURACION DEL MENSAJE
            _Message.[To].Add(Correo) 'Cuenta de Correo al que se le quiere enviar el e-mail
            If CorreoAgente.Length > 0 Then
                _Message.CC.Add(CorreoAgente)
            End If
            Dim data As Net.Mail.Attachment = New Net.Mail.Attachment(Adjunto)
            data.Name = "Cotizacion - " & N_Pedido & ".pdf"
            _Message.Attachments.Add(data)
            _Message.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("cotizaciones@miempresa.com.mx", "Cotizaciones miempresa", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8) 'Quien lo envía
            _Message.Subject = Asunto 'Sujeto del e-mail
            _Message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 'Codificacion
            _Message.Body = Mesaje 'contenido del mail
            _Message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
            _Message.Priority = System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.Normal
            _Message.IsBodyHtml = True

            'ENVIO
            _SMTP.Send(_Message) : Send = True

        Catch ex As System.Net.Mail.SmtpException : Send = False : End Try
        'Enviar Correo--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    End Sub
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y el problema cual seria?

Answer (score 0):

ya puede resolver el como mandarlo, dejo el código usado
gracias por nada.

```
 Public Sub EnviarCorreoEvento(Correo As String, Agente As String, Asunto As String, CuerpoMensaje As String, Cliente As String, Horainicio As DateTime)
        Dim msg As MailMessage = New MailMessage()
        msg.From = New MailAddress("cotizaciones@miempresa.com", "Alertas app")
        msg.[To].Add(New MailAddress(Correo, Agente))
        msg.Subject = Asunto
        msg.Body = CuerpoMensaje
        Dim str As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
        str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR")
        str.AppendLine("PRODID:-//Schedule a Meeting")
        str.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0")
        str.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST")
        str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT")
        str.AppendLine(String.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", Horainicio.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmss")))
        str.AppendLine(String.Format("DTSTAMP:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.UtcNow))
        str.AppendLine(String.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", Horainicio.AddMinutes(60).ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmss")))
        str.AppendLine("LOCATION: " & Cliente)
        str.AppendLine(String.Format("UID:{0}", Guid.NewGuid()))
        str.AppendLine(String.Format("DESCRIPTION:{0}", msg.Body))
        str.AppendLine(String.Format("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:{0}", msg.Body))
        str.AppendLine(String.Format("SUMMARY:{0}", msg.Subject))
        str.AppendLine(String.Format("ORGANIZER:MAILTO:{0}", msg.From.Address))
        str.AppendLine(String.Format("ATTENDEE;CN=""{0}"";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:{1}", msg.[To](0).DisplayName, msg.[To](0).Address))
        str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VALARM")
        str.AppendLine("TRIGGER:-PT15M")
        str.AppendLine("ACTION:DISPLAY")
        str.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:Reminder")
        str.AppendLine("END:VALARM")
        str.AppendLine("END:VEVENT")
        str.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR")
        Dim smtpclient As System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient = New System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient()
        smtpclient.Host = "mail.miempresa.com"
        smtpclient.Port = 587
        smtpclient.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("cotizaciones@miempresa.com", "micontraseña")
        Dim contype As System.Net.Mime.ContentType = New System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/calendar")
        contype.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST")
        contype.Parameters.Add("name", "Cita.ics")
        Dim avCal As AlternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(str.ToString(), contype)
        msg.AlternateViews.Add(avCal)
        smtpclient.Send(msg)
    End Sub
```